# Maximal torus in linear algebraic groups and Lie algebras

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, linear-groups

Let be $T \subset G$ a maximal torus in a linear algebraic group. I was looking for some link between definition in lie algebras' theory and linear algebraic groups' theory. In particular: If $Lie(G)=\mathfrak{g}$ is the lie algebra generated by $G$, we have $\mathfrak{t} \subset \mathfrak{g}$. Now $G$ is linear algebraic so I can think it as a subgroups of $GL(n,\mathbb{K})$. Let be $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{K}$, it's true that $\mathfrak{t}$ is maximal toroidal as lie subalgebras? There is a corrispondence, in this case, between the two definition of toral in Lie Algebras' theory and Linear Algebraic Groups' theory?

Comment: Would you remind us what the definition of a maximal toroidal subalgebra of a general Lie algebra is? I am only familiar with it in the case of semisimple $\mathfrak g$.

Comment: We are in the case of linear groups so the lie algebras are in $\mathfrak{gl(n)}$ and so I think that the definition it's the same of the case of semisimple lie algebras. A maximal subalgebra such that every element is semisimple.

Comment: What is a semisimple element of a general subalgebra of some $\mathfrak{gl}(n)$? Unless the Lie algebra is semisimple, that can depend on the chosen embedding. If I take the one-dimensional abelian Lie algebra and identify it with $\pmatrix{x&0\\0&x} \subset \mathfrak{gl}(2)$, all its elements are semisimple; if I identify it with $\pmatrix{0&x\\0&0} \subset \mathfrak{gl}(2)$, only $0$ is.

Comment: Ok... Could you resolve the problem if $g$ is semisimple or not?